# Norm-paradox of normal endomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let A be a normal endomorphism $A:V\rightarrow V$ and V is a unitary vector space. Now every normal endomorphism is unitary diagonalizable, meaning: $A=QDQ^{-1}$ for some unitary matrix $Q$ and $D$ is a digonal matrix.

Now we have if $||.||$ is an arbitrary operator norm, that $||A||=||QD\bar{Q^{-1}}||=||D||=spec(A)$ where $spec(A)$ is the spectral radius of the matrix and $||Q||=1$ as  Q is unitary.

But if I have a look at: $A=
\begin{pmatrix} 2 & -1 & -1 \\ -1 & 2 & -1 \\ -1 & -1 & 2  \end{pmatrix} $then it has $spec(A)=3$ but obviously $||A||_1=4$, which is a contradiction to the proof I gave above, although A is symmetric and therefore also normal. where am I wrong?

Comment: "obviously $\|A\|_1=4$": What is $\|\cdot\|_1$?  Are you using the correct norm?

Comment: @JonasMeyer The OP is talking about operator norm, so $\|A\|_1$ means the induced $1$-norm, i.e. the maximum column sum norm $\|A\|_1=\max_j\sum_i|a_{ij}|$.

Comment: @user1551 Thanks. Lipschitz: What I missed was where you wrote, "...if $||.||$ is an arbitrary operator norm...." That statement is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no contradiction, because $\|\cdot\|_1$ is not unitarily invariant, therefore $\|QDQ^\ast\|_1\neq\|D\|_1$ in general. All operator norms, except the $2$-norm, are not unitarily invariant.